# Magento 2.4 , Query execution was interrupted, query_timeout exceeded

Tags: magento2.4, reindex

its given when indexing Category Products index
`Category Products index process error during indexation process: SQLSTATE[70100]: <<Unknown error>>: 1907 Query execution was interrupted, query_timeout exceeded, query was: INSERT INTO` catalog_category_product_index_store2_tmp `(`category_id`,` pr
oduct_id`,` position`,` is_parent`,` store_id`,` visibility`) SELECT` cc`.`entity_id`AS`category_id`,` ccp`.`product_id`,` ccp`.`position`, 1 AS` is_parent`, 2 AS` store_id`, IFNULL( cpvs.value, cpvd.value)` 
who can help me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you're encountering during the indexing process (specifically, the Category Products index) is due to a query timeout. This error occurs when a SQL query takes longer to execute than the allowed time limit (query_timeout).

There could be several reasons why this is happening:

Large catalog size: If you have a large number of products and categories, the indexing process can take a considerable amount of time, potentially exceeding the query timeout limit.

Limited server resources: Insufficient server resources, such as CPU or memory, can slow down the indexing process, leading to query timeouts.

Database performance: The performance of your database server may also affect the execution time of the query. Slow performance or high load on the database server can cause query timeouts.

Customizations or third-party extensions: Custom code or third-party extensions that interact with the Category Products index could negatively impact the indexing process.

To resolve the issue, you can try the following:

1. Increase the query timeout limit: You can increase the query_timeout
   value in your MySQL configuration (my.cnf or my.ini) to allow longer
   execution time for queries. Make sure to restart the MySQL server
   after making changes.
2. Optimize the database: Perform database optimization and
   maintenance, such as cleaning up old data or optimizing tables, to
   improve the database server's performance.
3. Review customizations and extensions: Check for any custom code or
   third-party extensions that might be causing the indexing process to
   slow down. Disable or optimize them if needed.
4. Upgrade server resources: If your server is struggling to handle the
   indexing process due to limited resources, consider upgrading to a
   more powerful server or optimizing your server's resource
   allocation.

Remember to always backup your data and test changes in a staging or development environment before applying them to your production site.

Comment: thanks for answer.
Did everything right, but the problem is not solved, the count of products is 80000, can this be a problem?

Comment: @Robinio have you reached out to your hosting provider?

Comment: thanks, problem solved when i wrote the hosting provider. he changed some things in connection with mariaDb

Comment: What are these "some things"?